# Does CrOS have an equivalent to Window's Task Manager/Process Explorer, in the context of hung system remediation?

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, operating-systems, chromebook, google-chrome-os

So in Windows, when the system starts to hang and say, .e.g., folders are stuck in unresponsive state.  We can invoke Task Manager/Process Explorer directly via shortcut input <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, kill `explorer.exe`, then open `Run` dialogue and reinvoke `explorer.exe`.

However, in CrOS I'm not aware of any comparable procedure when a process hangs up the user space.  Up to this point, I've only been able to wait for it to either time-out and offer to close the offending process through a NR prompt, or for the system to altogether unrecoverably crash and reboot.

Is there any procedure or method to preemptively circumvent any loading/timeout counters, diagnose/kill the offending process(es), and if necessary reinvoke them?  On a related note, is there any way to easily invoke `chrome://gpuclean/` while Chrome itself is unresponsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've yet to test this solution myself, but I was browsing some unrelated Reddit posts and happened upon [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/cab1m/how_to_stop_running_a_script_in_idle/c0r703m?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share&context=3) comment which — if I've understood correctly — should serve as an answer to my question:

> On Windows I'd use the Task Manager or Process Explorer, maybe Mac OS
> has something comparable. If not, you can do what I do in Linux: open
> a shell, type `ps aux` to find the Process ID, and then `kill -9 12345`, where 12345 is the Process ID for the python process.